# while developing android webrtc video chat ,web to mobile fine, but mobile to mobile not working

Tags: android, webrtc

while developing android Webrtc video chat ,web to mobile fine, but mobile to mobile not working.
*emphasized text*

Comment: ok, and what is the question?

Comment: call not connected in one device(user1) to another(user2)

Comment: and the question is...? please, **ask a question**.

Comment: how can i add turn server to webrtc

Comment: i got error like this peer connection failed

Answer (score -1):

Use some player for downstreaming.. Like Exo player. Your question is not clear. But I think you are facing problem in downstreaming. Simple take the url from your server on which the user is online and play that url in exo player or any other player.. It simple.